# how to write data to xml file and save that xml in android application

Tags: android, xml

i am new developer in android application.i would like to write the data into xml file.i mean i would like to change the content like elements,tags,data in xml file.i can able to read an xml file in that file, i would like to change or modify and save that xml file.

i have written sample application to read xml as follows

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/book.xml");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println ("Xml file content====>"+strLine);


  data1.append(strLine);
  data1.append('\n');


  System.out.println("--------->"+data1.append(strLine)+"\n");
```

i have written this code in a method here **book.xml** is my xml file to change

when i call this method then i am getting out put with tags in logcat as follows

```
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): #######>>>>><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Employee-Detail>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Employee>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_Id>E-001</Emp_Id>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_Name>Vinod</Emp_Name>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_E-mail>Vinod1@yahoo.com</Emp_E-mail>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): </Employee>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Employee>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_Id>E-002</Emp_Id>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_Name>Amit</Emp_Name>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_E-mail>Amit2@gmail.com</Emp_E-mail>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): </Employee>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Employee>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_Id>E-003</Emp_Id>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_Name>Deepak</Emp_Name>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): <Emp_E-mail>Deepak3@hotmail.com</Emp_E-mail>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): </Employee>
06-14 12:48:32.309: VERBOSE/(433): </Employee-Detail>
```

how can write or edit or modify the above xml as prophetically?

please any body can help

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a parser for your xml (use SAX for example) and store it into a object of a class which represents the fields and values of you xml.

Then edit the needed settings in the object and use a xml builder to make a xml file with the new values.

Then just write the file back to the device. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for details on storing files.